# Unable to generate test classes with Randoop

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, randoop

Hello everyone I am using Randoop and when I try to generate some test cases I run the command and I get  the following error :

D:\Progetti\Junit_test\lib>java -classpath "D:\Progetti\Junit_test\out\production\Junit_test;D:\Progetti\Junit_test\lib\randoop-all-4.2.4.jar" randoop.main.Main gentests --testclass ="
com.company.Circle"
Randoop for Java version "4.2.4, branch master, commit be6dbd3, 2020-07-14".

Illegal argument --testclass==com.company.Circle, should be a class name

As I have seen some tutorial online the classpath contains two path , the first to the location of the .class instance of the class I want to test , the second to the location of Randoop.

Comment: Your command line looks incorrect:  there are spurious spaces, such as between `--testclass` and the following `=`.  Either you should correct that, or please update the question with the command line you actually ran.  I also suspect there are also missing newlines, such as before "Randoop for Java".  The message you say that Randoop produced `--testclass==com.company.Circle` has two `=` and thus is inconsistent with the command line.  Please paste in the *actual* command and error message.

Comment: Yes the problem was the spurious space thanks a lot for the help